# what collation to use if i want to make my nvarchar types to be sorted in same order in sql server as they would be in java using unicode

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a column which has characters which are not english e.g below are values

1. "Svensk Sjöföda AB"
2. "Suprêmes délices"
3. "Split Rail Beer & Ale"
4. "Speedy Express"
5. "Specialty Biscuits, Ltd."
6. "Spécialités du monde"
7. "Simons bistro"
8. "Seven Seas Imports"
9. "Save-a-lot Markets"
10. "Santé Gourmet"

when i sort then using order by clause in sql server i get different ordering than what i get when i do sorting of strings in java.

How do i make them same order?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the order above the order that you expect? Can you explain or link to some documentation that explains how Java sorts strings? What data type is the column in your table and what does your `SELECT` statement look like? What version of SQL Server do you have? What collation does your database have? I put your values above into an `NVARCHAR` column and when I queried them with `ORDER BY [column] DESC` I got exactly the order you showed here. That's with the `SQL_Latin1_CP1_CI_AS` collation.

Comment: i have SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation .
my query is very simple. e.g. select column1 from table order by column1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in java docs a class Called java.text.collator.
We can create own  implementation  of this class to match the collation we want for ordering.
there is already one implementation RuleBasedCollator.

Thanks for reading this question , using collator class solves my problem.